# In "The Silmarillion", why did not all the creatures living in total darkness become evil/deformed?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Large stretches of time pass in *The Silmarillion* with there being no Sun. And when it comes, it's like a little "prop" that just looks nice on the sky.

Does this not meant that all the Elves and humans were stumbling around in basically total darkness, possibly with some slight star light every now and then?

Should this not have caused them all to basically slowly mutate into Gollums, or even spider-like creatures? Is not the sun what gives energy and life and is associated with beauty rather than the scary darkness? How did all the trees and flowers grow without the sun rays giving them energy, etc.?

Comment: Keep in mind Gollum became what he was largely because of the ring and also it was in his nature before he got the ring. I don’t have my copy handy, but did those life forms exist in middle earth before there was light?

Answer (score 18):

[Middle-earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth) is *middle* because it lay in a middle region of Arda between two lamps—one silvery (Illuin), one golden (Ormal). After these lamps were cast down, the Two Trees —one silvery (Telperion), one golden (Laurelin)—were created to illuminate Valinor, and stars kindled in the sky were the light elsewhere in the world. The Elves awoke under the stars, so they were not 'stumbling around' in the dark, although they and other creatures lived for a time in only starlight. Men awakened/came after the sun rose.

Illúvatar the creator is what gives life in Tolkien's mythology… things like the biological necessity of sunlight for [primary production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_production) through photosynthesis in plants does not really enter into it.

Comment: Also, Yavanna "set a sleep upon many things that had arisen in the Spring, so that they should not age, but should wait for a time of awakening that yet should be." (Of the Coming of the Elves and the Captivity of Melkor)

Comment: No, that is not why Middle-Earth is "middle". None of the geology from the time of the Lamps remains, it was all destroyed in wars with Morgoth. It is 'middle' in exactly the same sense as the Norse Midgard.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is the 'Midgard' link only out of universe? I may well be misremembering the in-universe. Got a pointer for the in-universe use of the name?

Comment: @Lexible    In universe Middle-earth might have been middle because it was originally the middle continent on a flat Earth, with the eastern lands east of Middle-earth and Aman west of it..  And the name would have remained after Eru made the world spherical and it no longer had a middle area.  That is a guess.  Didn't Tolkien write at least one description of the world from the Elvish viewpoint?  How did that justify the "middle" in Middle-earth?

Answer (score 1):

Melkor's influence:

> darkness he used most in his evil works upon Arda, and
> filled it with fear for all living things.

Darkness by itself isn't evil, but merely the absence of anything at all. Only where Melkor exerts his influence does it become evil.

So Melkor would have had to target specific things to corrupt them into evil. Light is beautiful in whatever form it's taking, whether starlight, or the light of the sun or moon, but that doesn't make darkness worse except by contrast.

It is *not* explained why Melkor never corrupted any light, but only destroyed it.

In any case, it is easy to imagine Yavanna having created some creatures far underground that are always in total darkness that Melkor never found, and would continue in their existence free from evil influence.

Answer (score 0):

I believed it remains Middle-Earth due to the time of mingling light of the original two lamps and then later of the Two Trees when one waned and the other waxed and thus that point/region upon the land that enjoyed that in-between time, silvery-gold all at once, twilight and dusk, for Arda reckoned time in exactly 12 hours each of silver and of gold in those bygone ages.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I'm not really sure how this answers the question, though. Could you edit it to make the explanation a bit clearer? It'd also help if you added some supporting evidence, such as one or more quotes from the source material.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  As noted in one of the other answers, after the lamps were cast down the trees illuminated only Valinor and the rest of Arda was illuminated only by the stars.